# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'revision.revision_user' in 'field list': after Update from 8.2 to 8.4

Tags: 8

I'm encountering an error when updating from 8.2 to 8.4, in my case it seems to be related to block_content and maybe also commerce. I've found others with similar issues, but no solid resolution. Has anyone experience this?

Here is the error in the error log:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: 
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'revision.revision_user' in 'field list': SELECT revision.revision_id 
AS revision_id, revision.langcode AS langcode, revision.revision_user 
AS revision_user, revision.revision_created AS revision_created, 
revision.revision_log AS revision_log, base.id AS id, base.type AS 
type, base.uuid AS uuid, CASE base.revision_id WHEN 
revision.revision_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isDefaultRevision
FROM 
{block_content} base
INNER JOIN {block_content_revision} revision ON revision.revision_id = 
base.revision_id; Array
(
)
" at /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php 
line 686
```

When I try to run `drush entity-updates`, it errors out with this:

```
block_content entity type : 
  The Revision create time field needs to be updated.
  The Revision user field needs to be updated.
Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Exception thrown while 
performing a schema update. [error]
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'revision_created' in 'where clause':
SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{block_content_revision} t
WHERE revision_created IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array
(
)
 in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage-
>wrapSchemaException() (line 1513 of /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Fatal error: Cannot use Drupal\entity\BundleFieldDefinition as 
BundleFieldDefinition because the name is already in use in /modules/commerce/src/ConfigurableFieldManager.php on 
line 8
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                            
[error]
Error: Cannot use Drupal\entity\BundleFieldDefinition as 
BundleFieldDefinition because the
name is already in use in
/modules/commerce/src/ConfigurableFieldManager.php, 
line 8
The external command could not be executed due to an application 
error.
```

Any help is appreciated, the site is down

Comment: Have you tried going via 8.3?

Comment: Not yet, but perhaps I will try that tomorrow if I don't find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the update.php / drush updb process after updating the code?

Comment: Yes, updatedb seemed to work successfully and now shows `No database updates required                                                                  [success]
Cache rebuild complete.                                                                       [ok]
Finished performing updates. `

Comment: This is not Commerce related.

Comment: See: [Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'revision.revision_user' in 'field list'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2865702).

Answer (score 1):

As per this [comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2865702#comment-12174875), this could be related to *Dynamic Entity Reference* module as per this [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference/issues/2895963).

The solution is to apply this [patch](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/dynamic_entity_reference/commit/?id=b5e4fc2) or upgrade to the latest version of this module.

To fix the problem manually, you need to rename the field in the database from `revision_user` to `revision_user_int`.

Another suggestion from [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2865702#comment-12322707) says to add: `$settings['update_free_access'] = TRUE;` into your settings file and run `/update.php` to invoke the database updates again.